# Fetch value of token from component.ts in home.ts page

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Token for push notification is generated in `app.component.ts`. I want to read the generated `token` in `home.ts` page.

I have created `user.service.ts`, `import` it in `app.component.ts` and `home.ts`

I added the value of token in `this.user.token` in `app.component.ts` as shown below

```
  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();

      //for android push
      this.fcm.getToken().then(token => {
        console.log(token);
      });

      //Add this function to refresh the FCM token.
      this.fcm.onTokenRefresh().subscribe(token => {
        console.log(token);       // i can see value of token in console
        this.user.token = token;  // passing the value of token here
      });
```

and in `home.ts` when I `console.log(this.user.token);` , it is coming blank

```
ngOnInit(){
console.log(this.user.token);  // I cannot see value of token in home.ts
}
```

Token I generated, if i `console.log` from `app.component.ts` I can see it, but I cannot bring it to `home.ts`.

What am I missing ?

Comment: you cant access the variable from another component as it is, you need a service

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly use the variable of another component, You should save the value in the service then you can get it in another component, since you already injected the service

```
 constructor (private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {
   console.log(this.authService.user.token);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope your `user.service.ts` has a property called `token` inject your service in your `app.component.ts` constructor like below,

```
constructor(private userService: UserService){}
```

in app.component.ts as you have done

```
this.fcm.onTokenRefresh().subscribe(token => {
        console.log(token);       // i can see value of token in console
        this.userService.token = token;  // passing the value of token here
      });
```

Now if you inject userService in the constructor in `home.ts` you will be able to access the value of token as `this.userService.token`

Else

you can pass the token as an input to your `home.component.ts` if it is a child component. Like below

```html
<home [tokenValue]="token"></home>
```

Comment: ofcourse i have both  of these, i posted myquestion because after doing it, it is not working

Comment: Can you post the src of two components? That would give more detail on this question